# Does an accessory need to be MFI compliant if it's connected to my iOS application through Lightning to USB Adapter?

Tags: ios, external-accessory, mfi

I'm creating an app that will access an external device connected to an iPhone through a Lightning to USB 3 Camera Adapter. According to the External Accessory framework documentation, I need to declare protocol strings for all external accessories in Info.plist. Does the external device need to be MFI compliant and have protocol strings, even if I'm connecting it to an iPhone through an official Apple Lightning to USB Camera Adapter? Will I need protocol strings for the Lightning to USB adapter?

I'm testing the connection using the official EADemo that uses the External Accessory framework, but no device appears on the list.

Comment: The accessory needs to be MFi certified and connect directly to the Lightning port to work with the external accessory framework. You can't use the camera adapter to connect USB devices to your app.

Comment: So I can't use the camera adapter to connect an external device to my own apps? Is it used only for downloading photos and videos? I tested the adapter with Logitech keyboards and headsets and the iPhone recognized and used those accessories normally. Do they use standard protocols that don't require the accessories to be MFi certified?

Comment: Yes, you can connect devices that iOS has in-built drivers for; devices such as keyboards and audio devices. It can't be used for MFi devices

Comment: That clarifies a lot of things, thank you very much.